# Clickable Dropdown List Images

Tags: javascript, html

So, what I'm trying to do here is make a clicker game. I want the enemy to be selectable from a dropdown list, and then you can click whichever enemy you select to add to your resources (of which there are four for this game). However, when I use this code, the clickable images won't show up. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Here's the HTML and the Javascript from the sections I'm working on (the other sections have already been tested to see that they work). The images it's referring to are in the same folder and the onclick functions have already been written, and were tested with a non-dropdown list image and worked. The dropdown list worked for a non-clickable image. They just don't seem to work when I put them together.

```js
function changeE(){
 var dropdownList = document.getElementById('changeEid');
 var selectedIndex = dropdownList.selectedIndex;
 var selectedValue = dropdownList.options[selectedIndex].value;
 
 var enemyDiv = document.getElementById('enemyHere');
 switch(selectedValue){
  case 'DestroyerPrincess':
   enemydiv.innerHTML = '<img src="B1-DestroyerPrincess.png" width="445px" height="590px" onclick="fuelClick(1);ammoClick(1); steelClick(1); bauxiteClick(1)">';
   break;
  case 'LightCruiserDemon':
   enemydiv.innerHTML = '<img src="B2-LightCruiserDemon.png" width="424px" height="616px" onclick="fuelClick(1);ammoClick(1); steelClick(1); bauxiteClick(1)">';
   break;
   }
 };
```

```html
 Enemy
 <select id="changeEid" onclick="javascript:changeE();">
  <option value="DestroyerPrincess">Destroyer Princess</option>
  <option value="LightCruiserDemon">Light Cruiser Demon</option>
  </select>
 <div id="enemyHere">
 </div>
```

Comment: Di you try with the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a typo. In JavaScript part of code, replace `enemydiv.innerHTML` by `enemyDiv.innerHTML`

```js
function changeE(){
    var dropdownList = document.getElementById('changeEid');
    var selectedIndex = dropdownList.selectedIndex;
    var selectedValue = dropdownList.options[selectedIndex].value;

    var enemyDiv = document.getElementById('enemyHere');
    switch(selectedValue){
        case 'DestroyerPrincess':
            enemyDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="B1-DestroyerPrincess.png" width="445px" height="590px" onclick="fuelClick(1);ammoClick(1); steelClick(1); bauxiteClick(1)">';
            break;
        case 'LightCruiserDemon':
            enemyDiv.innerHTML = '<img src="B2-LightCruiserDemon.png" width="424px" height="616px" onclick="fuelClick(1);ammoClick(1); steelClick(1); bauxiteClick(1)">';
            break;
            }
    };
```

Comment: OH! Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't see that. I feel like a dummy, haha. It's working now! Thanks! I guess sometimes it takes an extra pair of eyes to see a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onclick i suggest you to use onchange event:

```
<select id="changeEid" onchange="javascript:changeE();">
        <option value="DestroyerPrincess">Destroyer Princess</option>
        <option value="LightCruiserDemon">Light Cruiser Demon</option>
</select>
```

with select tags i always use onchange it's better because you only want changes to be made when the user selects something it does make sense , i hope this helps

Comment: Naw, it didn't fix the problem. Besides, I used onclick for a different selection and it worked. I think the problem is in the option coding. Thanks though.